# SqlAlchemy Multi language support

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have next model for SqlAlchemy:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)

# I dont want list of all title translations: titles = db.relationship("Content"). 
# How can I pass lang_code here for properly title value?
    title = db.relationship("Content",
                            primaryjoin="and_(Content.post_id==Post.post_id,
                            Content.lang_code=='%s')" % lang_code, uselist=False)
class Content(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'content'
    content_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String())
    lang_code = db.Column(db.String(2)) # for ex: 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'ru'
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.post_id'))
```

I want to get Post contains 'en' title without list of all translations in my code. I want to pass lang_code value into it but I don't know how. 
And access it with something like this:

```
result = Post.query.filter_by(author_id=1).pass_custom_var_to_all_posts_in_query(lang_code='en').paginate(page, 20, False)
```

Or, may be, there are exists way to filter child rows (and show one title with current language instead of list of all titles)

Comment: 1) What DB are you using? 2) When you query, do you want to return only posts that have a title translation available in that language? Ie, exclude the post if a translation isn't available?

Comment: 1) Postgresql 2) I want return all posts with properly translation or with default language (en) if translation unavailable

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Association Proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-dictionaries) with [`attribute_mapped_collection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/collections.html#sqlalchemy.orm.collections.attribute_mapped_collection).

Your model somewhat reworked:

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    post_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String) 
    created_at = Column(DateTime)

    _titles = relationship(
        "Content",
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("lang_code"),
    )

    titles = association_proxy(
        '_titles', 'lang_code',
        creator=lambda k, v: Content(lang_code=k, value=v),
    )


class Content(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'content'
    content_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String())
    lang_code = Column(String(2))  # for ex: 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'ru'
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.post_id'))
```

Then you can create `Post` instances:

```
p = Post(
    name="no english",
    titles={
        'de': 'liebe',
        'es': 'amor',
    },
)
session.add(p)
```

Adding/Updating is a simple as `p.titles['it'] = 'amore'`, and deleting as `del p.titles['it']`.

Finally, your query with filter for `Title` which have translation to the specific language:

```
q = (
    session.query(Post)
    # .filter(Post.author_id == 1)
    .filter(Post.titles.contains('en'))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this https://sqlalchemy-i18n.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
this library will give the ability to create table for translation for each model and get the localized data

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store the translations directly as JSON in a field.

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, VARCHAR

class JSONEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):
    """Enables JSON storage by encoding and decoding on the fly."""
    impl = VARCHAR

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(JSONEncodedDict, nullable=False)
```

```py
p = Post(
    title={
        'en': 'Title',
        'de': 'Titel',
    },
)
session.add(p)

title_en = p.title.get('en', 'default')
title_de = p.title.get('de', 'default')
```